# How to think about and represent probability of an event happening

Tags: probability

Please bear in mind I am neither a statistician nor a mathematician. Plus I thought there was a Stats SE site I could post it to, but I can't find one.

**Context**
I have got into a "debate" about how long it might take a person (or people) to assess a stack of pictures to determine an exact match (between people's faces). My debater was thinking along the lines of a Cartesian product and I asserted it could be dramatically reduced by breaking the pictures up into mutually exclusive sub-classes and only working the sub-classes to reduce the size of the domain (and using triangle-numbers rather than product)

I have successfully worked out that the number of comparisons required drops sharply as you sub-classify, but the number of comparisons I can calculate is for the totality of the comparisons, i.e. assuming the single match was only found in the last possible comparison, how many would you need to do (and therefore what is the worst case time assuming one comparison per second).

For the purposes of my debate I used 600 pictures and asserted these could be sub-divided into four categories giving an equal number of 150 pictures per category. I ended up with each category requiring 11,175 comparisons to determine if there is a match between any two pictures in that category.

**Question**
Let's say you had to do 100 comparisons as a worst case, with a single match being randomly distributed. I assume that the odds of finding it in the first comparison is 1 in 100 and the odds of finding it in the *next* comparison gets steadily higher (i.e. 1 in 99, 1 in 98 etc.) as you progress.

How do I express this in a practical sense? How do I describe the changing odds over time? What is the best way to say "well you might have to wait until you've done X comparisons, but there is a [something] likelihood you'll find the match after only Y comparisons".

Sorry, this doesn't even sound like a Mathematics question even to me. But I feel as if there is some mathematical language I need to grasp that is just slightly out of reach! Apologies if I am a) too simplistic and b) off-topic

Comment: The Statistics site is *Cross Validated*. The experts may, however, be at one of the Computer Science sites.